# SpriteBatch.Draw has Padding on Monogame.Android

Tags: c#, android, monogame, visual-studio

I am using Monogame to create a small Android game.
I am trying to draw a sprite to the Android screen but it seems to have a padding of some pixels. The same game works fine on desktop.

How can I remove the padding?
The graphic itself has no borders etc; the problem is also reproducible with any other sprite.

I have created a new project in VS2019 with the Monogame templates for VS2017 and tried to reproduce this behavior in a new project.

It seems that the problem has something to do with the notch of my emulator.
In an emulator without a notch the problem seems to be non existent.
I found this [thread](http://community.monogame.net/t/weird-rendering-issue-on-phones-with-a-notch/11719) on the Monogame community but it hasn't got any answers.

My source code looks in its simplest form now as follows:

```
    private Texture2D _texture;

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        _texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("BasicTV");
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        spriteBatch.Draw(_texture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);

        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

The result of this code is this:

[image]

The Game is compiled for Android 8.1 and I use the Monogame framework 3.7.1.

Comment: What size is the texture? If it's not a power-of-2, have you checked if your Android GPU supports non-power-of-2 textures? Likewise, there may be a requirement for width to be a multiple of 4.

Comment: @MaximusMinimus It is now height:1024  width:2048. The behavior stays the same. In Landscape mode the padding is much smaller but still observable. In the real app I have a transformation matrix which makes the small padding to appear bigger and it is on the top and the bottom, which leads me to think that if i had a big enough picture you could observe the same problem in my little demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying several things it seems that it is a problem with version 3.7.1 of Monogame. I switched to Version 3.6 and the padding is gone. I will update this answer/question if I find the reason why 3.6 behaves differently then 3.7.1

Edit:
I switched to version 3.8 and the problem seemed to still exist.
But it seems that with this little snippet the problem could be  fixed ([found here](https://community.monogame.net/t/android-fullscreen-not-working-properly/7611/11)) .

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        //...
        HideSystemUI();
        g.Run();
    }
    private void HideSystemUI()
    {
        SystemUiFlags flags = SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation | SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen | SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
        this.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)flags;
    }
```